# Can Henzie blitz cards exiled with Atsushi?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I play a [Henzie "Toolbox" Torre](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Henzie%20%22Toolbox%22%20Torre) commander deck. I blitz [Atsushi, the Blazing Sky](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Atsushi%2C%20the%20Blazing%20Sky). When it dies I decide to use its first ability to exile the top two cards of my library.

If those two cards are creatures with mana value four or greater can I then blitz them with Henzie from exile?

The relevant abilities are:

Henzie:

> Each creature spell you cast with mana value 4 or greater has blitz. The blitz cost is equal to its mana cost.

Atsushi:

> When Atsushi, the Blazing Sky dies, choose one —
>
> - Exile the top two cards of your library. Until the end of your next turn, you may play those cards.
> - Create three Treasure tokens.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, you may blitz applicable creatures from exile.**

You blitz a card by casting it for the alternative mana cost granted by Blitz. Blitz makes no limitation on from where you may cast that creature, so casting it from your hand, from exile, or from anywhere else works all the same. You simply follow the normal spell casting procedure for alternative cost spells.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (**usually** the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs [..]

> 702.152a [..] “Blitz [cost]” means “You may cast this card by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost,” [..] Casting a spell for its blitz cost follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you would not be able to use Blitz if the creature is being cast with a different alternative cost. For example, if a creature is exiled using a Foretell ability then it cannot be blitzed.

Comment: You also can't use Blitz if a creature spell gets onto the stack without you casting it (e.g. the spell is copied) or if a creature gets onto the battlefield without being cast.