# Can you blitz adventure cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

This question is related to [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/59075/can-henzie-blitz-cards-exiled-with-atsushi) one.

If I destroyed an artifact with the sorcery part of [Stormkeld Vanguard](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stormkeld%20Vanguard) can I then blitz it with [Henzie "Toolbox" Torre](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Henzie%20%22Toolbox%22%20Torre) from exile?

Comment: What part of the Q&A you linked does not apply to your question?

Comment: I'm relatively certain it works, just interested in an canonical answer that I can bookmark and show my playgroup, it keeps getting up and people keep think I'm trying to sell them a baloney sandwich when I tell them it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you may blitz applicable creatures from exile.**

You blitz a card by casting it for the alternative mana cost granted by Blitz. Blitz makes no limitation on from where you may cast that creature, so casting it from your hand, from exile, or from anywhere else works all the same. You simply follow the normal spell casting procedure for alternative cost spells.

> 601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (**usually** the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs [..]

> 702.152a [..] “Blitz [cost]” means “You may cast this card by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost,” [..] Casting a spell for its blitz cost follows the rules for paying alternative costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.